# GraphQL API with Prisma and Zeit.now. Can't connect to server error

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql, vercel

I am attempting to deploy a GraphQL API along with Prisma and using Zeit.now. I am following the [prisma.io](https://www.prisma.io/docs/tutorials/deploy-prisma-servers/zeit-now-and-google-cloud-sql-mohj5eiwot#2.2-now-deployment-configuration) documentation and keep hitting a brick wall when I get to the deployment with "now" final step.

When I navigate to the now.sh url after deployment, I get a "Server cannot be reached" error and my schema side bar just shows a spinny.

I also followed the [howtographql.com](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/4-adding-a-database/) documentation on how to set up the GraphQL API and Prisma just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally realized my issue. I had forgotten to provide the "Authorization": "Bearer " to the GraphQL database site that was deployed. I feel a bit silly now but I am happy I have it working.